# dynamically set the dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this.

```
        $("#slot_+num  option[value='8']").remove();
```

if I do this

```
      $("#slot_0 option[value='8']").remove();
```

It works, but if I try to set the selector dynamically with variable num it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to concatenate the string an variable properly with `+`. You can tell something is wrong by the syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string, like this:

```
$("#slot_"+num+"  option[value='8']").remove();
```